# PDFBox: Remove text behind image

Tags: pdfbox

I am in a requirement to split a pdf into two, one with image and one with text. I dont want to remove the text which are behind an image and it should be the part of the image pdf. I want to extract only the top layered text in the PDF. Can any one help on this?

I already extracted the image and text into two pdfs by looping through pdf operators. I am facing trouble when not to remove the text behind the PDF.

Comment: You *"dont want to remove the text which are behind an image"* but what about text in front of some image?

Comment: *"I want to extract only the top layered text in the PDF"* - what do you mean technically by that, can that text somehow be recognized in a different way, is it e.g. in some special optional content group (as OCGs sometimes are called layers), or is it probably all the text drawn after the last image on the page is drawn?

Comment: Exactly, its the text drawn after the last image.But we are not sure how the PDF was created, it may be the image which was lastly drawn. I need the text which are not hidden by any image in the PDF.

Comment: *"Exactly, its the text drawn after the last image.But we are not sure how the PDF was created, it may be the image which was lastly drawn."* - This confuses me. Is it the text drawn after the last image or not?

Comment: In other words, i want to extract only the text which are above the image..

Comment: Please suggest a way to remove the hidden text and save it back as pdf itself.. I followed your VisibleTextStripper code. Its working fine, but I can't write back as PDF. It's working if we are using for text extraction alone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I followed your VisibleTextStripper code. Its working fine"* - ah, that's a good hint. I'm pretty busy currently but I'm trying to find some time these days.

Comment: Still I cant find out the solution. When I combine text and image PDF back, its not exactly look like the original one. Can I extract the background layer(with all the images, including text suppose if it was below the image) as 1 PDF and text layer on the top as 2nd?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you supply a sample PDF and point out which text to move to the text PDF and which text to move to the image PDF?

Comment: Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GZwYXeR1L70wYGOH3VYbUIbvYzu58bY2/view?usp=sharing
Subscribe Now! text is behind the image.. Also it have many hidden text.. I don't want to include "Subscribe now" text and hidden text in the text pdf.. I want it to be as part of the image pdf itself...

Comment: *"Subscribe Now! text is behind the image.."* - Actually only the "E NOW" is behind an image, the "SUBSCRIB" is not. What about "WHY SUBSCRIBE? DELIVERY AT YOUR DOOR STEP | RECEIVE YOUR COPY FIRST | NEVER MISS AN ISSUE"? It is not behind an image either, so it should go to the text PDF, shouldn't it?. What about "SAVE UP TO 50%"? This also is not covered by an image.

Answer (score 1):

Code for removing text:

```
PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(new File(inputfilePath), password);
        PDPageTree allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.getCount(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);

            parser.parse();
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();
            List newTokens = new ArrayList();
            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object token = tokens.get(j);
                if (token instanceof Operator) {
                    Operator op = (Operator) token;

                    if (op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                            "tj")) {
                        try {
                            // remove the one argument to this operator
                            newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Header doesn't contain versioninfo

                }
                newTokens.add(token);

            }
            PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
            ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(newContents.createOutputStream());
            writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
            // In writeTokens method, I closed the output stream.. This is
            // for future reference.. or it will throw stream not closed
            // error
            newContents.addCompression();
            page.setContents(newContents);
            if (DEBUG)
                System.out.println("Background image pdf creation process");
            document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
            document.save(outputFolder + "/img_" + fileName);
```

And for removing the images and shades, I used the below code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object token = tokens.get(j);
                if (token instanceof Operator) {
                    Operator op = (Operator) token;

                    // Text Extraction removing image and shades
                    if (op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("do") || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sh")

                            || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gs") || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bi")
                            || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id") || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ei")
                            || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bmc") || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bdc")
                            || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("emc") || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("m")
                            || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("w")
                            || op.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("re")

                    ) {
                        // remove the one argument to this operator
                        newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                newTokens.add(token);

            }
```